# jQuery fade between .html() changes

Tags: jquery

in the below code, how can I adjust to fade between the .html(); state changes? I have tried various incarnations of fadeIn() and fadeOut() but with no luck.

```
$(window).bind( 'load scroll', function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('.logo').html('<a>State 1</a>');
    } else ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
        $('.logo').html('<a>State 2</a>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to fade from one element to the same element with different contents.

What you can do instead is put your states in different elements both positioned in the same place, and crossfade between them.

```js
$(window).bind('load scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.state1').fadeIn();
    $('.state2').fadeOut();
  } else {
    $('.state1').fadeOut()
    $('.state2').fadeIn()
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative
}

#container a {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br><br><br><br> 
<div id="container">
  <a class="state1">State 1</a>
  <a class="state2">State 2</a>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Here I'm fading in/out both elements, but if the elements have a background color it's better to only fade the "topmost" element, leaving the bottom one alone (where it'll be hidden when "behind" the visible topmost element): that way you don't get the background peeking through during the crossfade.